# Apache Flex actionscript example using mx.controls assets (Label) compiled with mxmlc does not work

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, command-line-interface

I am using apache flex 4.14.1 on fedora 19 (kernel 3.14.27-100.fc19.x86_64).

Here's three examples. I'd expect all three to work but the first one (actionscript using mx library) does not. I've tried many variations. Even tried to generate an actionscript from the third example (mxml file using mx.controls library) to reverse engineer a working actionscript using the mx library to no avail. I'd appreciate any insights. Thanks.

---

Below actionscript example using mx.controls.Label does not work (hello world does not appear on the stage). In fact no other mx control object works.

Compiled using (There was no error during compilation):

```
  linux> mxmlc example.as
  linux> flashplayer example.swf
```

Code:

```
::::::::::::::
example.as
::::::::::::::
package {
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import mx.controls.*;
   public class example extends Sprite {
      public function example() {
         var myLabel:Label = new Label();
         myLabel.text = "Hello World";
         addChild(myLabel);
      }
   }
}
```

---

Below actionscript example works:

Compiled using:

```
  linux> mxmlc example1.as
  linux> flashplayer example1.swf
```

Code:

```
::::::::::::::
example1.as
::::::::::::::
package {
   import flash.text.TextField;
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   public class example1 extends Sprite {
      public function example1() {
         var txtHello:TextField = new TextField();
         txtHello.text = "Hello World";
         addChild(txtHello);
      }
   }
}
```

---

Below mxml example using mx library works:

Compiled using:

```
  linux> mxmlc example2.mxml
  linux> flashplayer example2.swf
```

Code:

```
::::::::::::::
example2.mxml
::::::::::::::
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
      <mx:Label id="simpleLabel" text="Hello World"/>
</mx:Application>
```